# best component / example code for an Outlook-style calendar in a C# windows forms program?

Tags: c#, winforms, calendar

Are there any existing libraries or sample programs for an Outlook-style calendar component, to be used in a C# windows form program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DevExpress has a [Scheduler control](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Scheduler/):

[image]

Overall, I am *very* satisfied with the quality of DevExpress: code, UI, support.

Answer (score 1):

Iirc from a previos project, ILOG have a component for this. I didn't use that one, so I can't comment on it - but the one I *did* use (Gantt) was exceptionally good. I was a very happy customer.

Answer (score 1):

I have used Infragistics in the past, this control library should fit your use case:

http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/winforms/winschedule.aspx#Overview

Comment: Here is a good one also: http://www.componentsource.com/products/syncfusion-essential-schedule-for-wpf/index-gbp.html